# How to learn about iPhone jailbroken programming?

Tags: iphone, sdk, jailbreak

I'm interested in learning about what additional features and APIs an app has access to when an iPhone is jailbroken. Can someone provide me with some basic resources to learn about this? I would be most interested in:

- documentation on the private APIs
- filesystem layout
- app configuration, e.g. how did WinterBoard replace SpringBoard? Apps that replace the lockscreen?
- tools needed

Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: I actually asked a similar question a while ago. Check out some of the responses I got here [What does jailbreak do to the iPhone technically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668867/what-does-jailbreak-do-to-the-iphone-technically). Hope this helps!

Comment: If your interested in this question why not support the Area 51 proposal for a [jail-breaking Stack Exchange site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18154/ios-jailbreaking-development?referrer=EuWVi6IpN0_KzzEhC7I-Qw2)

Answer (score 7):

Very good question. I've personally spend quite a bit of time on trying to find documentation on the private APIs, and even though I'm pretty sure I've come across it some time ago, right now I can't really find it anymore. However, I do have some answers to your questions. Let me share what I have so far:

#### Filesystem layout

- An old, but still mostly true [guide](http://www.forgeniuses.com/2008/10/04/iphone-21-hacking-getting-around/#high_2) on filesystem layout.

#### "Replacing" apps

I think most of the "hijacking" of original iPhone apps is based on catching and re-implementing objective-c messages through posing and comparable techniques. A good guide on this is available [here](http://www.culater.net/wiki/moin.cgi/CocoaReverseEngineering). I'm note entirely sure that this is the mechanism at work though.

#### Tools

- A [toolchain](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-dev/) for iphone dev is available on google code. See [this guide](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-dev/wiki/Building) for info   on how to install it.
- See [this guide](http://www.alexwhittemore.com/?p=354) for info on how to use the default apple Xcode environment for development on a jailbroken phone.

Comment: The guide linked to under 'replacing' apps is amazing! Exactly what I was looking for on the subject. Thanks so much for posting that!

Answer (score 1):

This is the best thing I'v found on the subject so far : 
[Jailbroken Development : Starter Pack](http://iky1e.tumblr.com/post/9561218739/jailbroken-development-starter-pack)