# iPhone developing FOR jailbroken devices (not USING jailbroken devices!)

Tags: iphone, background, geolocation, jailbreak

I would like to dig into developing for jailbroken devices, just to test what the device could do. I would like, for instance, to alter the ipod music based on geo-location, so i have to program a new daemon that runs in background and fetch gps informations at regular interlavs and then make something with them.

Longitude, [longitude](http://www.technivations.com/iphone/longitude), for instance, does exactly this, even when the device is locked, and then upload the informations on google latidude.

I have some experience as an iphone developer, but i'm not sure on where to find documentation to accomplish such a task. I know about the books "iphone open application development" and "the iphone developer's coockbook", but i don't own them and i'm not sure they have what i'm looking for.

Any advice on this?

Comment: This is a duplicate of this recent question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759660/how-to-learn-about-iphone-jailbroken-programming

Comment: in the question i ask information about two books and about a specific task, that is different from the tasks the "duplicate" question is about. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone else interested, i found a good example here: [libactivator](http://github.com/rpetrich/libactivator).